# custom view component into based view

Tags: python, django, view

how to make a custom component (for example a form) that can then be called from other views?
for example

```
class BaseFormView (FormView):
   template_name = 'pit / contact.html'
   form_class = ContactForm
   success_url = '/'

   def form_valid (self, form):
       return super (). form_valid (form)


class TestView (View):
   template_name = loader.get_template ('pit / pit.html')
   title = "test"

   def get (self, request, * args, ** kwargs):
       view = BaseFormView ()
       context = {"title": self.title, "view": view}
       return HttpResponse (self.template_name.render (context, request))
```

i want to call it from a different kind

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load templetags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    {{ view }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. since you already have a form class i.e. ContactForm, you can use it in any view you want. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i want to call it from a different view

`{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load templetags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        {{ view }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}`

Comment: Do you mean you want to render the things rendered in BaseForm view into TestView? Look into using `{% includes 'template_name.html' %}`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat
and how can I pass BaseFormView to include?

Comment: If you want the features of BaseFormView in multiple views why not just inherit the view in other views?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat
what if I need several different components in testview at once?

Comment: Python has Multiple Inheritance!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example, what you want is a mixin. This allows you to reuse code in your classes.

For example, you could use [`FormMixin`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/FormMixin/) to provide your form to various views.

```py
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin


class MyFormMixin(FormMixin):
   form_class = ContactForm
   success_url = '/'


class TestView(MyFormMixin, View):
   template_name = 'pit/pit.html'
   title = "test"

   def get (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context.update({"title": self.title})
       return HttpResponse(self.template_name.render (context, request))
```

The `FormMixin` will add the form to the context for you, [see here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/FormMixin/#get_context_data)

Then your template can use the form;

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load templetags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <form action="/" method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `<form action="/" method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>`

I can put it in a separate template and call it for example as {{forms}}?

Comment: You could put your form markup in a separate template and include it using something like `{% include 'includes/form.html' %}`